# Working with fragments - findViewById returns NULL on Button in Android

Tags: android-fragments, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I've started dealing with Fragments in Android. I created Activity with NavigationView which has 3 items and worked with 3 simple fragments till now. NavigationHeader has 2 buttons - 1 starts LoginActivity and 2nd RegisterActivity. I remind that everything till niw worked fine. Today I've tried to create RecyclerView inside one of the fragments. Now when I try to run app, findViewById applied to those 2 NavigationHeader buttons returns NULL. I have no idea why.

Here is HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String FRAGMENT_POSITION = "fragment_position";    // Fragment Position

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;                 // NavigationDrawer Layout
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;                    // NavigationView
    private CoordinatorLayout homeCoordinatorLayout;    // Coordinator Layout For Snackbar
    private Toolbar toolbar;                            // Application Toolbar
    private TextView navHeaderNamePlusSurname;          // Name And Surname Navigation Header Text
    private TextView navHeaderEmail;                    // E-mail Navigation Header Text
    AppCompatButton navHeaderButtonLogin;               // Login/Logout Button
    AppCompatButton navHeaderButtonRegister;            // Register Button
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;        // ActionBar Drawer Toggle
    private SQLiteHandler db;                           // SQLite Database Helper Class
    private SessionManager session;                     // Session Manager
    private int lastShownFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Setting Toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // Setting Up DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Navigation Header Logout Button
        navHeaderButtonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_btn_log_in_out);
        navHeaderButtonRegister = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_btn_register);
        Log.d("czy_null", "navHeaderButtonLogin: " + navHeaderButtonLogin + ", navHeaderButtonRegister: " + navHeaderButtonRegister);

        // Name, Surname And E-mail Texts
        navHeaderNamePlusSurname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_name_plus_surname);
        navHeaderEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_email);

        // SQLite Database Handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session Manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Navigation Drawer
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        // Checking If User Is Logged In
        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            hideNavigationViewGroup(nvDrawer);  // Hiding NavigationView Group Depending
                                                // If Not Logged
        } else {
            navHeaderButtonLogin.setText(getText(R.string.home_btn_log_out));
            navHeaderButtonRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Fetching User Details From SQLite
            HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
            String name = user.get(SQLiteHandler.KEY_NAME);
            String surname = user.get(SQLiteHandler.KEY_SURNAME);
            String email = user.get(SQLiteHandler.KEY_EMAIL);

            // Setting Navigation Header Texts
            String nameSurname = name + " " + surname;
            navHeaderNamePlusSurname.setText(nameSurname);
            navHeaderEmail.setText(email);
        }

        // Setting Up CoordinatorLayout
        homeCoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_coordinator_layout);

        // Setting Listener To NavigationView
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        // Setting Starting Fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            setStartingFragment();
        } else {
            restoreOnInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getInt(FRAGMENT_POSITION));
        }

        // Applying Login/Logout Button Listener
        setLoginButtonListener();

        // Applying Register Button Listener
        setRegisterButtonListener();
    }

    // Listener To Login/Register Button
    private void setLoginButtonListener() {
        navHeaderButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    logoutUser();
                    navHeaderNamePlusSurname.setText(getString(R.string.nav_header_name_surname));
                    navHeaderEmail.setText(getString(R.string.nav_header_email));
                    hideNavigationViewGroup(nvDrawer);
                    navHeaderButtonLogin.setText(getString(R.string.home_btn_log_in));
                    navHeaderButtonRegister.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    showSnackbarInfo(getString(R.string.inf_logout_success),
                            R.color.snackbar_success_msg);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    // Listener To Register Button
    private void setRegisterButtonListener() {
        navHeaderButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

    // Logging Out The User
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);
        db.deleteUsers();
    }

    // Setting Up DrawerToggle
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    // Setting Up Drawer Content
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);

                        return true;
                    }

                });
    }

    // Replace Existing Fragment With a New One
    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;

        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_top20_recipes: {
                fragmentClass = Top20RecipesFragment.class;
                lastShownFragment = 0;
                break;
            }

            case R.id.nav_kitchen_type: {
                fragmentClass = KitchenTypeFragment.class;
                lastShownFragment = 1;
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_meal_type: {
                fragmentClass = MealTypeFragment.class;
                lastShownFragment = 2;
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        menuItem.setChecked(true);      // Highlight The Selected Item
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());  // Updating Toolbar Title
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();   // Close The Drawer
    }

    // Function Setting First Fragment
    private void setStartingFragment() {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = Top20RecipesFragment.class;

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        lastShownFragment = 0;
        MenuItem menuItem = nvDrawer.getMenu().getItem(0);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);      // Highlight The Selected Item
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());  // Updating Toolbar Title
    }

    // Saving Fragment Title State
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt(FRAGMENT_POSITION, lastShownFragment);
    }

    // Restoring Fragment Title States
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        restoreOnInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getInt(FRAGMENT_POSITION));
    }

    // Restoring Selected Item On Screen Rotation Or App Minimalize
    private void restoreOnInstanceState(int lastPosition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;

        switch (lastShownFragment) {
            case 0: {
                fragmentClass = Top20RecipesFragment.class;
                break;
            }

            case 1: {
                fragmentClass = KitchenTypeFragment.class;
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                fragmentClass = MealTypeFragment.class;
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        lastShownFragment = lastPosition;
        MenuItem menuItem = nvDrawer.getMenu().getItem(lastPosition);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);      // Highlight The Selected Item
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Function Hiding Items In NavigationView
    private void hideNavigationViewGroup(NavigationView nvDrawer) {
        nvDrawer.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.nav_group_logged_user, false);
    }

    // Function Showing Snakcbar
    private void showSnackbarInfo(String info, int textColor) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(homeCoordinatorLayout, info, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

        View sbView = snackbar.getView();

        TextView sbText = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        sbText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), textColor));

        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment which has to contain RacyclerView:

```
public class KitchenTypeFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView kitchenTypeRecycleView;
    private ArrayList<KitchenTypeItem> kitchenTypeItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        kitchenTypeItems = new ArrayList<>();
        fillKitchenTypeArray(kitchenTypeItems);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kitchen_type, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        kitchenTypeRecycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.kitchen_type_recycle_view);

        kitchenTypeRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        kitchenTypeRecycleView.setAdapter(new KitchenTypeAdapter(kitchenTypeItems,
                R.layout.kitchen_type_grid_item));
        kitchenTypeRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
        kitchenTypeRecycleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }

    private void fillKitchenTypeArray( ArrayList<KitchenTypeItem> kitchenTypeItems) {
        KitchenTypeItem kitchenItem;

        // Currently 8 Kitchen Types
        String[] itemNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.kitchen_types);

        // Filling ArrayList
        for(int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
            kitchenItem = new KitchenTypeItem(itemNames[i], R.drawable.example_kitchen_type);
            kitchenTypeItems.add(kitchenItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is XML from HomeActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".SignUpActivity">

        <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_layout_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
        <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is NavigationHeader XML with those 2 buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_nav_header"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- Name + Surname, E-mail -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_lin_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Name + Surname Text -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_header_name_plus_surname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="@string/nav_header_name_surname" />

            <!-- E-mail Adress -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_header_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:text="@string/nav_header_email" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nav_lin_layout">

        <!-- Login/Logut Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_btn_log_in_out"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/nav_header_login_color"
            android:textColor="@color/text_icons"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_log_in" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_btn_register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/nav_header_register_color"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:textColor="@color/text_icons"
            android:text="@string/btn_sign_up" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is finally XML from Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/kitchen_type_fragment"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.fragments.KitchenTypeFragment">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/kitchen_type_recycle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If I comment those lines: setLoginButtonListener() and setRegisterButtonListener() everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use findViewById on the headerView like this:

> navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById()

Comment: The problem was inside google newest library. Last update messed sth up. Using previous version od the library solved that problem.